# Lucene.net result as string / parsing to slow

Tags: vb.net, lucene.net

I need some help to speed up the lucene.net search.
We need the result in a string with ; as a seperator.
The parsing of the topdocs takes to long:

```
    Dim resultDocs As TopDocs = indexSearch.Search(query, indexReader.MaxDoc())
    Dim hits As Object = resultDocs.ScoreDocs

    Dim strGetDocIDList As String = ""

    For Each sDoc As ScoreDoc In hits
        Dim documentFromSearcher As Document = indexSearch.Doc(sDoc.Doc)
        Dim contentValue As String = documentFromSearcher.Get("id")

        strGetDocIDList = strGetDocIDList + Path.GetFileName(contentValue) + ";"

    Next

    Return strGetDocIDList
```

How can we speed this up?

Regards
Ingo

Comment: what do you mean by takes too long, do you have any metrics? Also how many fields do you have in your documents and what size are they?

Comment: i get the hits (~800000) in a second the for each takes nearly 6minutes with this among of results! There are two fields in the Document. one with the fulltext and another with only an ID.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to tune performances for loading STORED fields in Lucene.

First, by default its loads every stored fields of the `Document` when you load it. Only store what you need and do not systematically store everything.

If you dont need to load all the stored fields for this particular query, try writing a `FieldSelector` to gain further control on field loading.

Finally, add the Field you load the stored data for more often before other stored fields in your Documents. Fields are loaded sequentially and in some cases, adding them first to Documents can speed up things a little bit.

[FieldSelector API link](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/FieldSelector.html)

[An article that may help you with implementing a FieldSelector](http://kb.ucla.edu/articles/why-are-lucenes-stored-fields-so-slow-to-access)